# upload image from multiple form with ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, upload

in PHP page with multiple form tag to register user information.
using ajax to collect data and post to register PHP page now i want to upload image to server folder but i failed.

my html code:

```
<label for="upimage" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mb-75 mr-75">Upload Image</label>
<input type="file" id="upimage" hidden accept="image/*" name="image"/>
```

Javascript Code:

```
let data1 = document.getElementById('data1').value,
    data2 = document.getElementById('data1').value,
    data3 = document.getElementById('data1').value,
    upimage = document.getElementById('upimage').value;
$.ajax({
    url:"././newregister.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{action:'newregister', data1:data1, data2:data2,
        data3:data3, upimage:upimage},
    success:function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

newregister php code:

```
$uploads_dir = './uploads';
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    echo "Sucsess"; 
}
else
{
    echo "Error" . $_FILES["file"]["error"] ; 
}
```

> ERR: Undefined index: file in .... on line ....

Comment: You should post a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object.

Comment: i know but to manage my data in register php file i need to send it by data.

Comment: Do you know how convert this type of data to FormData by append or otherway?

Comment: You create a FormData object (new FormData()), then append the values to it. Another way may be to set up a form in html, with type (method?) multipart/formdata, and post that with a submit button/function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given by [POST method uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

> Be sure your file upload form has attribute enctype="multipart/form-data" otherwise the file upload will not work.

Your current solution lacks enctype, that's why your file is not getting uploaded to the server and therefore isn't in the superglobal variable $_FILES.

---

As [ferikeem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67703756/upload-image-from-multiple-form-with-ajax-and-php#comment119670119_67703756) already said. Wrap your data in a FormData Object and send it that way.
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5976031/10887013

**JavaScript**

```js
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append("you_file_key_here", $("#upimage")[0].files[0]);
fd.append("data1", $("#data1")[0].value);
fd.append("data2", $("#data2")[0].value);
fd.append("data3", $("#data3")[0].value);

$.ajax({
    url: "././newregister.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$_FILES["file"]`, here is your problem.

In `$_FILES` array key `"file"` doesn't exists. As I see you need to change `$_FILES["file"]` with `$_FILES["upimage"]`.

Comment: No I write this codes for sample and that's not working with $_FILES["upimage"] too.